# Determine Store Averages Per State

Tags: sql, sql-server, plsql

A STATE has specific stores

I need to display the AVERAGE sales for all stores on each row .

```
select 
    tbl_Mill_FAS.Mill_Name,
    tbl_Zone_FAS.Zone_Name,
    tbl_Station.Station_Name,
    tbl_Daily_Data.dValue, 
    AVG(tbl_Daily_Data.dValue)
from tbl_Mill_FAS
inner join tbl_Zone_FAS on tbl_Zone_FAS.Zone_Id = tbl_Mill_FAS.Zone_Id
inner join tbl_Station on tbl_Station.Station_Id = tbl_Mill_FAS.Station_Id
inner join tbl_Daily_Data on tbl_Daily_Data.Daily_Id = tbl_Mill_FAS.Daily_Id
group by 
    tbl_Mill_FAS.Mill_Name,
    tbl_Zone_FAS.Zone_Name,
    tbl_Station.Station_Name,
    tbl_Daily_Data.dValue


State  - Pongola

Store1 - Mass Mart - Sales: $4000 - Avg: $1669
Store2 - Wallmart  - Sales: $333  - Avg: $1669
Store3 - CNN       - Sales: $674  - Avg: $1669
```

Comment: Why is `plsql` tagged? Are you using both SQL Server and Oracle? What version? Could you supply some sample data so we know how you got your results?

Comment: You would need to show sample data for all tables (`tbl_Mill_FAS`, `tbl_Zone_FAS`, `tbl_Station`, `tbl_Daily_Data`), and the corresponding expected results.

Comment: The query needs to be as per the output. Perhaps you got a fundamental solution

Comment: use analytic /window function `avg(tbl_daily_Data.dvalue) over (partition by Zone_Name)` so you get the average over the whole zone?  assuming zone is state in this example...

Comment: I need to the get the average of all stores in Pongola and display that in the current select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    select 
        tbl_Mill_FAS.Mill_Name,
        tbl_Zone_FAS.Zone_Name,
        tbl_Station.Station_Name,
        tbl_Daily_Data.dValue, 
        AVG(tbl_Daily_Data.dValue),
AVG(tbl_Daily_Data.dValue) over (partition by tbl_Mill_FAS.Mill_Name)
    from tbl_Mill_FAS
    inner join tbl_Zone_FAS on tbl_Zone_FAS.Zone_Id = tbl_Mill_FAS.Zone_Id
    inner join tbl_Station on tbl_Station.Station_Id = tbl_Mill_FAS.Station_Id
    inner join tbl_Daily_Data on tbl_Daily_Data.Daily_Id = tbl_Mill_FAS.Daily_Id
    group by 
        tbl_Mill_FAS.Mill_Name,
        tbl_Zone_FAS.Zone_Name,
        tbl_Station.Station_Name,
        tbl_Daily_Data.dValue
```